# Find specific pattern in string using C#

Tags: c#, regex, string

I am trying to find, and remove, a specific pattern inside a string with C#.

The pattern is an asterisk, followed by any number of numbers, followed by .txt

Example strings:

1. test*123.txt
2. test2*1.txt
3. test*1234.txt3
4. test4*12.txt123

Given these examples, the desired results would be:

1. test ("*123.txt" was removed)
2. test2 ("*1.txt" was removed)
3. test3 ("*1234.txt" was removed)
4. test4123 ("*12.txt" was removed)

How can this be accomplished?

Comment: You should look into the specifics of regular expressions. Here is a cheat sheet:
http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/46/CSharp-Regular-Expressions-Cheat-Sheet

Comment: Does *any* number of numbers include 0?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
string pattern = @"\*\d*\.txt";
Regex rgx = new Regex(pattern)
input = rgx.Replace(input, "");
```

Answer (score 8):

If you build a regular expression and replace its matches with an empty string, you're effectively removing that pattern. Here's what you'll need for your pattern:

1. An asterisk has a special meaning in a regular expression (zero or more of the previous item), so you'll have to escape it with a backslash (`\*`).
2. You can match a digit with the digit character class (`\d`) or with an explicit class that includes all of them (`[0-9]`). There are differences between them because of culture settings: `\d` can match things like eastern arabic numerals (٠.١.٢.٣.٤.٥.٦.٧.٨.٩), while `[0-9]` will match only the hindu-arabic numerals (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9).
3. You can use a `+` quantifier to match one or more of the previous item: `\d+` will match one or more digits.
4. A dot is another special character (it matches any single character except for newlines). It will also need escaping (`\.`).
5. You can match text without special characters with the text itself: `txt` matches exactly `txt`.

Putting everything together we get:

```
string purged = Regex.Replace(input, @"\*[0-9]+\.txt", "");
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use RegEx to solve this. I recommend an online editor to help you do this. It's called Rubular and can be found at http://www.rubular.com/